# MySQL SET Data Type

Tags: mysql, set

I tried to make a column in my database table with `SET` data type to store in it data in this format: `10,2,44`, like this: `SET('A' , 'B' , 'C')`.

When I try to insert data, I get this response:

> Error Code: 1265. Data truncated for column 'setcol' at row 1

And this is my query:

```
INSERT INTO `voting`.`questionnaires` (`name`, `cat_id`, `init_date`, `end_date`, `setcol`) VALUES ('sad', '2', '2008-02-02', '2008-02-02', 'A, B');
```

Should I use specific format? Does `SET` accept repetition?

Comment: What happens if you take out the space: `A,B` instead of `A, B`?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set your desired value you would store a `3` (without quotes) instead of `'A,B'`.  That is because values in a `SET` field are stored numerically in bitwise fashion. So each value in a set definition corresponds to on/off bits in a binary number.

Therefore you statement would be:

```
INSERT INTO `voting`.`questionnaires` (`name`, `cat_id`, `init_date`, `end_date`, `setcol`) VALUES ('sad', '2', '2008-02-02', '2008-02-02', 3);
```

For example, from the [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set.html):

> For a column specified as SET('a','b','c','d'), the members have the
> following decimal and binary values.

[image]

So since `A` has a value of `1` and `B` has a value of `2`, add them together and you get `3`. Or to set `C` and `D` you would store `12`, etc.

For this reason, it's ill-advised to have numbers as members of a `SET` field (as you hinted you might) since storing `'5'` has a completely different meaning than storing `5`.